# Is the curl of the gradient of a scalar field always zero?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

Its obvious that if the curl of some vector field is 0, there has to be scalar potential for that vector space.
$\nabla\times\mathbf{G}=0 \Rightarrow \exists \nabla f=\mathbf{G}$

This clear if you apply stokes theorem here:
$\int_{S}(\nabla\times\mathbf{G})\cdot d\mathbf{A}=\oint_C (\mathbf{G})\cdot d\mathbf{l}=0$

And this is only possible when **G** has scalar potential.

Hence proved. But now considering the converse of the statement.. For a scalar field $f$

Applying stokes theorem in reverse yields:
$\oint_C (\nabla f)\cdot d\mathbf{l}=\int_{S}(\nabla\times\nabla f)\cdot d\mathbf{A}=0$

Now I'm not sure how to prove that $\nabla\times\nabla f=0$ from this step. Or is the case that this may not be true always. I'm unsure how to proceed from here. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Curl of a gradient is always zero (with $C^2$ regularity): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Curl_of_gradient_is_zero
See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4133105/conservative-vector-field-with-non-zero-curl?noredirect=1

Comment: Is there a simpler way to approach this problem @Robert Z

Comment: Try this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4320018/divergence-of-curl-is-zero-coordinate-free-approach?

Comment: Thank you, by applying a similar argument here i.e a point on the surface where the curl of the gradient is non zero, since its continuous there is an region on the surface that gives non zero curl. Then I can just make sure the initial curve lies inside this area, therefore creating a contradiction.